# C - error: expected identifier or '(' return 0;

Tags: c

Been trying to sort this out for hours.

I am building a general test code to try and work in a function prototype and use it to find a simple solution.

The goal is to have the user input a float value for biweekly salary (I.E. 200.00, etc) and have the program take the function and output 24months * the biweekly amount.

For some reason I am getting an error and cant figure it out...

**The error is:**

```
prog.c:32:1: error: expected identifier or '('
return 0;
^
1 error generated.
```

Any help would be awesome :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Function prototype
float YearPay(float value);

int main()
{

/* variable definition: */
float biweekly, totalYear;
biweekly = 1.0;

/* Prompt user for biweekly salary */

while (biweekly > 0.0)
{
    printf("Enter your standard bi-weekly check value after tax:\n ");
    scanf("%f", &biweekly);

if (biweekly > 0.0)
{
    // Call the YearPay function
    totalYear = YearPay(biweekly);
    printf("The yearly total monetary value with bi-weekly paychecks in the\
    amount of %f is %f\n",biweekly,totalYear);
}
else
    printf("Bi-weekly salary must be greater than 0.0!\n");
    }
}

return 0;

/* Function returning the yearly total value of all paychecks */
float YearPay(float value)
{
    return (float)value*24;
}
```

Comment: Your `return 0` is outside of `main`.  Move it above the `}` that's right above it.

Comment: Yet again a question that is asked because OP doesn't care to indent code properly!!!

Comment: Still learning @AnttiHaapala... My apologies for not knowing everything in my first 2 months of coding..

Comment: There are tools that will indent your code for you. `indent` is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
else
    printf("Bi-weekly salary must be greater than 0.0!\n");
    }
}

return 0;
```

to

```
else
    printf("Bi-weekly salary must be greater than 0.0!\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

You would see this easily if you would format the code (now it is hard to read).

Comment: An alternative diagnosis: the `{` after `else` is missing, and the `}` after `return 0;` is missing.  The net result is the same.